# R: disentangling scopes

Tags: r, scope

My question is about avoiding namespace pollution when writing modules in R.

Right now, in my R project, I have `functions1.R` with `doFoo()` and `doBar()`, `functions2.R` with other functions, and `main.R` with the main program in it, which first does `source('functions1.R'); source('functions2.R')`, and then calls the other functions.

I've been starting the program from the R GUI in Mac OS X, with `source('main.R')`.  This is fine the first time, but after that, the variables that were defined the first time through the program are defined for the second time `functions*.R` are sourced, and so the functions get a whole bunch of extra variables defined.

I don't want that!  I want an "undefined variable" error when my function uses a variable it shouldn't!  Twice this has given me very late nights of debugging!

So how do other people deal with this sort of problem?  Is there something like `source()`, but that makes an independent namespace that doesn't fall through to the main one?  Making a package seems like one solution, but it seems like a big pain in the butt compared to e.g. Python, where a source file is automatically a separate namespace.

Any tips?  Thank you!

Comment: if i could add one feature the stnd distribution, this would be it. I would really like to do this sort of thing:  "import timeseries as TS"

Comment: Creating a package with `package.skeleton` is not difficult and will provide a lot of benefits in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main function you want to use is `sys.source()`, which will load your functions/variables in a namespace ("environment" in R) other than the global one. One other thing you can do in R that is fantastic is to attach namespaces to your `search()` path so that you need not reference the namespace directly. That is, if "namespace1" is on your search path, a function within it, say "fun1", need not be called as `namespace1.fun1()` as in Python, but as `fun1()`. [Method resolution order:] If there are many functions with the same name, the one in the environment that appears first in the `search()` list will be called. To call a function in a particular namespace explicitly, one of many possible syntaxes - albeit a bit ugly - is `get("fun1","namespace1")(...)` where `...` are the arguments to `fun1()`. This should also work with variables, using the syntax `get("var1","namespace1")`. I do this all the time (I usually load just functions, but the distinction between functions and variables in R is small) so I've written a few convenience functions that loads from my `~/.Rprofile`.

```
  name.to.env <- function(env.name)
    ## returns named environment on search() path
    pos.to.env(grep(env.name,search()))

  attach.env <- function(env.name)
    ## creates and attaches environment to search path if it doesn't already exist
    if( all(regexpr(env.name,search())<0) ) attach(NULL,name=env.name,pos=2)

  populate.env <- function(env.name,path,...) {
    ## populates environment with functions in file or directory
    ## creates and attaches named environment to search() path 
    ##        if it doesn't already exist
    attach.env(env.name)
    if( file.info(path[1])$isdir )
      lapply(list.files(path,full.names=TRUE,...),
             sys.source,name.to.env(env.name)) else
    lapply(path,sys.source,name.to.env(env.name))
    invisible()
  }
```

Example usage:

```
populate.env("fun1","pathtofile/functions1.R")
populate.env("fun2","pathtofile/functions2.R")
```

and so on, which will create two separate namespaces: "fun1" and "fun2", which are attached to the `search()` path ("fun2" will be higher on the `search()` list in this case). This is akin to doing something like

```
attach(NULL,name="fun1")
sys.source("pathtofile/functions1.R",pos.to.env(2))
```

manually for each file ("2" is the default position on the `search()` path). The way that `populate.env()` is written, if a directory, say "functions/", contains many R files without conflicting function names, you can call it as

```
populate.env("myfunctions","functions/")
```

to load all functions (and variables) into a single namespace. With `name.to.env()`, you can also do something like

```
with(name.to.env("fun1"), doStuff(var1))
```

or

```
evalq(doStuff(var1), name.to.env("fun1"))
```

Of course, if your project grows big and you have lots and lots of functions (and variables), writing a package is the way to go.

Comment: In my function I have logical `reload` argument which if set to `TRUE` cause `detach` if there is already attach exact name. It helps when your codes are modified often during analysis.

Comment: in the `attach(NULL, ...)`, it should be `attach(NULL, name="fun1")`

And thanks, this is really great!

Comment: doh! @rescdsk - thanks for pointing that out. I made the change above for others looking to do something similar. and @Marek - I also thought about what to do when the environment is already attached... mine just loads the modifications into the existing environment, but I agree that your way might be cleaner as it does not retain deleted functions or variables if they are deleted from the sourced code.

Comment: @rescdsk - you can also create a new environment not on search() list with something like myenv <- new.env(), and use newenv as the argument to 'envir' (rather than using pos.to.env() or name.to.env()) for the functions get(), assign(), with(), within(), or evalq() to set and get variable/function values in or from your environment(s).

Answer (score 5):

I would explore two possible solutions to this.

a) **Think more in a more functional manner**. Don't create any variables outside of a function. so, for example, main.R should contain one function main(), which sources in the other files, and does the work. when main returns, none of the clutter will remain.

b) **Clean things up manually**:

```
#main.R
prior_variables <- ls()
source('functions1.R')
source('functions2.R')

#stuff happens

rm(list = setdiff(ls(),prior_variables))`
```

Comment: I do agree that most variables should be kept in a local environment (e.g., within functions).

Answer (score 3):

If you switch to using packages, you get namespaces as a side-benefit (provided you use a NAMESPACE file).  There are other advantages for using packages.

If you were really trying to avoid packages (which you shouldn't), then you could try assigning your variables in specific environments.

Comment: I don't really have anything against packages, except that it takes many steps to make them.  As far as I can tell, you have to do package.skeleton(), then R CMD build, then R CMD install --- do I have to do this each time I make a change to my code?  It seems like a clumsy way to do development.

Comment: There are numerous upsides to packaging, and that has been discussed often here for us not to rehash. If you don't like it, you don't use it. Your loss, not mine :)  That said, for small incremental changes you have other options (fix(), edit(), source(), ...) but for anything with some structure, somewhat frequent use, larger than minuscule size, ... I tend to like packages.  A lot.

Answer (score 3):

Well avoiding namespace pollution, as you put it, is just a matter of diligently partitioning the namespace and keeping your global namespace uncluttered.

Here are the essential functions for those two kinds of tasks:

### Understanding/Navigating the Namespace Structure

At start-up, R creates a new environment to store all objects created during that session--this is the "global environment".

```
# to get the name of that environment:
globalenv()
```

But this isn't the root environment. The root is an environment called "the empty environment"--all environments chain back to it:

```
emptyenv()
returns: <environment: R_EmptyEnv>

# to view all of the chained parent environments (which includes '.GlobalEnv'):
search()
```

### Creating New Environments:

```
workspace1 = new.env()

is.environment(workspace1)
returns: [1] TRUE

class(workspace1)
returns: [1] "environment"

# add an object to this new environment:
with(workspace1, attach(what="/Users/doug/Documents/test_obj.RData",
     name=deparse(substitute(what)), warn.conflicts=T, pos=2))

# verify that it's there:
exists("test_obj", where=workspace1)
returns: [1] TRUE

# to locate the new environment (if it's not visible from your current environment)
parent.env(workspace1)
returns: <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

objects(".GlobalEnv")
returns: [1] "test_obj"
```

Coming from python, et al., this system (at first) seemed to me like a room full of carnival mirrors. The R Gurus on the other hand seem to be quite comfortable with it. I'm sure there are a number of reasons why, but my intuition is that they don't let environments persist. I notice that R beginners use 'attach', as in attach('this_dataframe'); I've noticed that experienced R users don't do that; they use 'with' instead eg,

```
with(this_dataframe, tapply(etc....))
```

(I suppose they would achieve the same thing if they used 'attach' then 'detach' but 'with' is faster and you don't have to remember the second step.) In other words, namespace collisions are avoided in part by limiting the objects visible from the global namespace.